# Single word meaning 'filter out noise'/remove background sources

Tags: single-word-requests

As noted in the title, I am looking for a single word, preferably short, that relates to filtering out noise/unwanted things/background noises.

Comment: It’s not a single word, but how about ‘cleaning up’? You can clean up an image, a soundclip, a video, etc., and unless context suggests something else, it would usually be taken to mean removing noise of some kind or other. More specific terms include _noise reduction_ and _denoising_.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Not sure if it's technically correct but is this what 'isolating the signal' means?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_reduction

That is the "official" term. Noise-Reduction

Answer (score 1):

In the technical world, in one word we call this **separation**. The full expression is *source separation*, and there are various methods for doing it that involve complicated mathematical analysis.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_separation):

> Source separation problems in digital signal processing are those in which several signals have been mixed together into a combined signal and the objective is to recover the original component signals from the combined signal.

Here is an interesting demonstration, called the *[Cocktail Party Demo](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/cocktail/cocktail_en.cgi)*, that really illustrates what is accomplished with **separation**. This demo, by the way, only illustrates one approach to separating signals, and there are others that work under different conditions (including when you only have  single microphone or sensor, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean people filtering out background noises that they don't want to hear? You could say they were *blanking* extraneous noise. Or quite simply *not listening*! We're all quite capable of *tuning off* to things that don't concern us.

Answer (score -1):

Anechoic is defined as echo and reverberation sound-absorbent

Musicians records in an anechoic chamber.

> They are also insulated from exterior sources of noise. The combination of both aspects means they simulate a quiet open-space of infinite dimension, which is useful when exterior influences would otherwise give false results.
>
> Anechoic chambers were originally used in the context of acoustics (sound waves) to minimize the reflections of a room. **More recently, rooms designed to reduce reflection and external noise** in radio frequencies have been used to test antennas, radars, or electromagnetic interference.

http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/180916